# Unable to start amplify mock InternalFailure: The request processing has failed because of an unknown error, exception or failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I have just tried to start my `amplify mock` service and received the follow error:

`InternalFailure: The request processing has failed because of an unknown error, exception or failure.`

This has previously worked, a few hours ago with no resets or other changes.

To fix this, I did have success with removing amplify completely, doing `amplify init & amplify add api` but this means I lose my local data each time, but it happens randomly multiple times in the last few hours.

For the full log while error is taking place:

```
hutber@hutber:/var/www/unsal.co.uk$ amplify mock

GraphQL schema compiled successfully.

Edit your schema at /var/www/unsal.co.uk/amplify/backend/api/unsalcouk/schema.graphql or place .graphql files in a directory at /var/www/unsal.co.uk/amplify/backend/api/unsalcouk/schema
Failed to start API Mock endpoint InternalFailure
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem probably comes from the SQLite file use for the mock (lock stories I guess). Delete the file in the **mock-data/dynamodb/your_db_file.db** folder and execute the again **amplify mock api**. The file recreates itself correctly. This avoids resetting the whole amplify project.